# How to change the Webview url to another url where it can be remote or changed by user

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm building a kiosk system with Java in Android Studio. I have a `Webview` in my app. But I don't want it to direct one specific url. I need to change the url occasionally, even after the users installed it. I don't know if it's possible and I haven't got a solution after searching around for a while.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.scholarscup.org");
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Exit!")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<WebView 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webview" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</WebView>
```

Comment: Could you explain by some example? You mentioned "I need to change the url occasionally", which way you want to change? By URL input from EditText of UI or get something from server response or...

Comment: For example, I have 5 different button to link different website and i install my apk on it and i just want to change the website url only so that i no need to install 5 different apk to the button. Let say that the kiosk is in Malaysia and I'm in Singapore and when i want to change the link, I can directly change my own and the kiosk there will automatically change too. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it like browser use EditText and Button to search if you want user enter url or if you want to use your urls use handler.postDelay() to change it after delay time

Comment: For example, I have 5 different button to link different website and i install my apk on it and i just want to change the website url only so that i no need to install 5 different apk to the button. How should I do?

Comment: @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    webview.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}